# Pytorch gradients has not calculated

Tags: python, pytorch

I create a NN. I'm having a problem with recounting gradients. The problem is that I scalarly multiply 2 tensors `u @ v` and normalize one of them. It is important that gradients cannot be calculated for h. Therefore, I use `detach()`. In addition, during the recalculation of gradients, normalization should not be taken into account (I do not know how to do this).

```
import torch
from torch import nn


class Nn(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Nn, self).__init__()
        self.ln = nn.Linear(5, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
        v = self.ln(x)

        u = v.clone()
        h = v.clone()

        u /= u.norm()
        h = h.detach()
        h /= h.norm()

        res = torch.stack([torch.stack([u @ h, u @ h])])

        return res


def patches_generator():
    while True:
        decoder = torch.rand((5, ))
        target = torch.randint(2, (1,))
        yield decoder, target


net = Nn()

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters())

net.train()
torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)
for decoder, targets in patches_generator():
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = net(decoder)
    loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

As a result, I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has
>   been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [9, 512, 1,
>   1]], which is output 0 of ReluBackward1, is at version 3; expected
>   version 2 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the
>   operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in
>   question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!

Comment: Is this the entire code? I don't see the Relu layer the error references.

Comment: This code has problem. I reduced them

Comment: where does `ReluBackward1` come from?

Comment: nvm, it's not relevant, you just probably copied the error message from your original code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the in-place division operator applied to `u` in this line:

```
u /= u.norm()
```

changing it to

```
u = u / u.norm()
```

makes the code run. The reason is that the in-place operator overwrites the intermediate result from this line

```
u = v.clone()
```

which makes it impossible for Pytorch to compute the gradient.

(The error message in the question contains a reference to a `ReluBackward1` layer which is not in the reduced code example. [Pytorch ReLU](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.ReLU) layers have an optional `in_place` argument which makes the operation in place while supporting backprop. This often works, because in a sequential network there is no need to distinguish between the output of the ReLU activation and the output of the weights to compute the gradient, but in more complex architectures it might be necessary to retain the output of the weights.)